# Infinite loop in pthread_from_mach_thread_np freezing app

Tags: ios, multithreading, pthreads, grand-central-dispatch, freeze

I am investigating an issue for an iOS app where the main thread appears to be hung. It believe I have reproduced it locally a couple times, but it is not very repeatable. I have attached a few example stack traces below where I have seen this.

I see a [dispatch_barrier_sync_f](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1453098-dispatch_barrier_sync_f?language=objc) call which “submits a barrier function for execution and waits until that function completes”. This is happening on a number of the other threads which are all waiting on a ulock_wait.

In all of the hangs, there is one thread that has a dispatch_barrier_sync_f which appears to be active. From what we could tell, it is stuck in the function pthread_from_mach_thread_np. I only have assembly code here, but [here is some source](https://github.com/apple/darwin-libpthread/blob/main/src/pthread.c#L940-L955). It appears to be converting from a mach_thread to a pthread. When I step through the assembly it appears to be stuck in the loop portion of iterating over the pthread list.

It is not clear to me how this fixed loop could hang. Perhaps the memory is corrupted and it is not looping over a valid pthread list?

This may be related to the issue posted [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/702626).

I have a few examples of this happening all from different services

Example 1:

```
thread #104, queue = 'com.apple.coremedia.decompressionsession.clientcallback'
frame #0: 0x00000001f17fc100 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_from_mach_thread_np + 68
frame #1: 0x0000000109139c98 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_introspection_continuation_get_info + 244
frame #2: 0x000000010913ae74 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_introspection_queue_item_enqueue_hook + 44
frame #3: 0x000000010913a42c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_introspection_queue_fake_sync_push_pop + 116
frame #4: 0x0000000109107f1c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_barrier_sync_f + 224
frame #5: 0x0000000197286720 VideoToolbox`__vtdsr_dequeueAllPendingFramesAndCallbackClientForEach_block_invoke + 1000
frame #6: 0x0000000109100c6c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
frame #7: 0x00000001091027bc libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 20
frame #8: 0x000000010910aa60 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 1428
frame #9: 0x000000010910b5e0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_invoke + 428
frame #10: 0x0000000109118168 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 908
frame #11: 0x00000001f17f60bc libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 288
```

Example 2:

```
thread #97
frame #0: 0x00000001f0b980ec libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_from_mach_thread_np + 48
frame #1: 0x00000001059f9c98 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_introspection_continuation_get_info + 244
frame #2: 0x00000001059fae74 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_introspection_queue_item_enqueue_hook + 44
frame #3: 0x00000001059fa42c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_introspection_queue_fake_sync_push_pop + 116
frame #4: 0x00000001059c7f1c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_barrier_sync_f + 224
frame #5: 0x0000000187fbbf54 CoreData`_perform + 176
frame #6: 0x0000000187e23a28 CoreData`-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _routeLightweightBlock:toStore:] + 204
frame #7: 0x0000000187ea71f4 CoreData`-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error:] + 368
frame #8: 0x0000000187e89f7c CoreData`_PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 296
frame #9: 0x0000000187ec357c CoreData`_PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 208
frame #10: 0x0000000187e25fc8 CoreData`_PF_ManagedObject_WillChangeValueForKeyIndex + 84
frame #11: 0x0000000187e3f260 CoreData`_sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 152
frame #12: 0x000000010128f408 MyApp`-[GMSTileDataCache touchCachedTile:] + 100
frame #13: 0x000000010128fb7c MyApp`__72-[GMSTileDataCache loadTileForTileCoords:dataVersion:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 216
frame #14: 0x0000000187e18834 CoreData`developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 156
frame #15: 0x00000001059c27bc libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 20
frame #16: 0x00000001059ca8a4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 984
frame #17: 0x00000001059cb5e0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_invoke + 428
frame #18: 0x00000001059d8168 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 908
frame #19: 0x00000001f0b920bc libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 288
```

Example 3:

```
thread #99, queue = 'flight logger queue'
frame #0: 0x00000001f16040f8 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_from_mach_thread_np + 60
frame #1: 0x0000000105909c98 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_introspection_continuation_get_info + 244
frame #2: 0x000000010590b0d0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_introspection_queue_item_dequeue_hook + 44
frame #3: 0x000000010590a440 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_introspection_queue_fake_sync_push_pop + 136
frame #4: 0x00000001058d7f1c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_barrier_sync_f + 224
frame #5: 0x000000019ac06cac libswiftDispatch.dylib`merged implicit closure #2 (() -> ()) -> () in implicit closure #1 (__C.OS_dispatch_queue) -> (() -> ()) -> () in __C.OS_dispatch_queue.sync<τ_0_0>(execute: () throws -> τ_0_0) throws -> τ_0_0 + 180
frame #6: 0x000000019ac05d0c libswiftDispatch.dylib`partial apply forwarder for implicit closure #2 (() -> ()) -> () in implicit closure #1 (__C.OS_dispatch_queue) -> (() -> ()) -> () in __C.OS_dispatch_queue.sync<τ_0_0>(execute: () throws -> τ_0_0) throws -> τ_0_0 + 56
frame #7: 0x000000019ac069ec libswiftDispatch.dylib`__C.OS_dispatch_queue._syncHelper<τ_0_0>(fn: (() -> ()) -> (), execute: () throws -> τ_0_0, rescue: (Swift.Error) throws -> τ_0_0) throws -> τ_0_0 + 396
frame #8: 0x000000019ac05dbc libswiftDispatch.dylib`__C.OS_dispatch_queue.sync<τ_0_0>(execute: () throws -> τ_0_0) throws -> τ_0_0 + 168
frame #9: 0x0000000100324f8c MyApp`FlightData.flightDataComponents(self=0x000000010645aee0) at FlightData.swift:184:35
frame #10: 0x000000010029c014 MyApp`DDLogDataFactory.generateLogDataComponent(now=2022-06-30 22:54:33 UTC, flightData=0x000000010645aee0, self=0x0000000287465280) at DDLogDataFactory.swift:197:44
frame #11: 0x0000000100364688 MyApp`DDFlightLogFormatterV1.flightData(flightData=0x000000010645aee0, self=0x0000000283461040) at DDFlightLogFormatterV1.swift:45:57
frame #12: 0x0000000100364768 MyApp`@objc DDFlightLogFormatterV1.flightData(_:) at <compiler-generated>:0
frame #13: 0x00000001001d06b4 MyApp`__31-[FlightLogger logCurrentData:]_block_invoke(.block_descriptor=0x0000000283bc01b0) at FlightLogger.m:408:30
frame #14: 0x00000001001d0e40 MyApp`__41-[FlightLogger executeBlockInBackground:]_block_invoke(.block_descriptor=0x0000000283bc22b0) at FlightLogger.m:457:9
frame #15: 0x00000001058d0c6c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
frame #16: 0x00000001058d27bc libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 20
frame #17: 0x00000001058da8a4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 984
frame #18: 0x00000001058db5e0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_invoke + 428
frame #19: 0x00000001058e8168 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 908
frame #20: 0x00000001f15fe0bc libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 288
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: If the function whose source you provided is blocking indefinitely, then the most likely culprit is the `_pthread_lock_lock(&_pthread_list_lock)` call.  That might be, but is not necessarily, related to this remark in [the docs of `dispatch_barrier_sync_f`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1453098-dispatch_barrier_sync_f?language=c): "Calling this function and targeting the current queue results in deadlock."

Comment: I doubt we can give you anything more specific without more information.  Our usual expectation is that debugging questions such as this will provide a [mre].  I appreciate that it would be difficult to prepare an MRE for a case such as this, but that does not change the fact that we generally need that kind and level of information to make confident diagnoses.

Comment: The combination of the barrier references and large thread numbers make me wonder if you have a thread explosion. The worker thread pool only has 64 threads, and if you exceed that, you can easily introduce problems. E.g., do you have unconstrained dispatches to concurrent queues?

Comment: But as John said, we really need MRE. So, make copy of your project and rip out as much unrelated kruft until the problem disappears. Or create new blank project, and add the bare minimum necessary to manifest one of these problems. The nice thing is, that in the preparation of a MRE, you often end up diagnosing (and therefore making it easy to solve) the problem.

Comment: BTW, that question you shared with us, with the `0x8badf00d` (aka, “ate bad food”), is a situation where the [watchdog process](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/addressing-watchdog-terminations/) reports that the main thread is blocked for too long. That can happen when some deadlock entangles the main thread. But unless you are specifically getting `0x8badf00d`, that may not be relevant here. Regardless, that question does not supply enough code in order to diagnose the issue, either.

Comment: @Rob and John , thank you very much for the comments.  I appreciate this is difficult/impossible to debug without an MRE.  Unfortunately, I don't think it would be possible to prepare one to replicate this issue. I am not seeing any references to 0x8badf00d in our crash reports but I will do some testing there.  I also did not know about the thread limit, I think you may be onto something there.  We do have a large number of services and threads.  I will investigate that further.  Thanks again!